# Gnome-keyring: "Automatically unlock this key whenever I'm logged in"

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, ssh, xubuntu, gnome-keyring

I don't seem to have the option to "automatically unlock this key whenever I'm logged in" when trying to SSH into another computer.

This is a screenshot of my prompt:
[image]

This is an example I found on some random website, but it shows where the option should appear:
[image]

I have `seahorse` `ssh-add` `ssh-agent` `ssh-askpass` and `seahorse-ssh-askpass` all installed. The `gnome-keyring-daemon` is running in the background as well. I'm not sure why the option is missing. 
I've also tried `ssh-add ~/.ssh/my_key` and `ssh-askpass ~/.ssh/my_key`. I'll get prompted for the private key password, but the password is still required when I follow up with an SSH command. Help!