# Disable autocheck of keyring's unlock "Automatically unlock this keyring whenever I'm logged in"

Tags: password, keyrings, seahorse, unlock

Everytime I am unlocking a keyring (seahorse), there is a checkbox

"Automatically unlock this keyring whenever I'm logged in".

Now the issue is that I most certainly don't want this to be autochecked or pre-checked.

I am looking for a way to either:

1. **disable the auto check (so the checkbox is *NOT checked by default*)**
2. remove this option to automatically unlock completely

I only found answers/questions relating to these topics which are ***NOT the purpose of this Q***:

1. checkbox missing - [Gnome-keyring: "Automatically unlock this key whenever I'm logged in"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1144809/gnome-keyring-automatically-unlock-this-key-whenever-im-logged-in)
2. how to autounlock - [The login keyring did not get unlocked when you logged into your computer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/918712/the-login-keyring-did-not-get-unlocked-when-you-logged-into-your-computer)
3. how to remove the lock - [How can I stop being prompted to unlock the 'default' keyring on boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/867/how-can-i-stop-being-prompted-to-unlock-the-default-keyring-on-boot)

**To be clear:** I want to ALWAYS type the password (I want to ALWAYS have the keyring locked) so I want to prevent any unwanted auto-unlocking ahead.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to limit yourself to ubuntu instructions as gnome-keyring is used across multiple distros that use gnome.

I found this https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GNOME/Keyring

> If you desire to skip the PAM step, the default keyring must be
> unlocked manually or via another method. See [#Launching
> gnome-keyring-daemon outside desktop environments](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GNOME/Keyring#Launching_gnome-keyring-daemon_outside_desktop_environments_(KDE,_GNOME,_XFCE,_...)) (KDE, GNOME,
> XFCE, ...) and the [GnomeKeyring wiki](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeKeyring/RunningDaemon).

Is that what your looking for?

Comment: Hi, this is my fault I didn't state it clearly in the question - I am not looking for a replacement of the keyring with another keyring, but rather configuring the default one. 
But maybe there's a way to actually configure this on the GNOME Keyring level? (since seahorse is using that https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Seahorse)

Comment: This isnt a replacement for the keyring. This will disable GNOME from poping up the keyring, and require you to manually unlock it through a terminal.

Comment: ok, so if it would require for it to be unlocked ***everytime*** that could be a usable workaround - could you provide an example how to set this up?